# Why don't these figures align horizontally?

Tags: positioning, subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to use the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package for horizontally aligning up some figures, and I did as the documentation instructs me to do, yet the result is these are vertically aligned. It really confuses me.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]

    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig/bed1.jpg}
        \subcaption{Bedroom 1}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig/bed2.jpg}
        \subcaption{Bedroom 2}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Two bedrooms}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second minipage is moved onto a new line because you have an extra line between the first `\end{minipage}` and the second `\begin{minipage}`. Check the documentation here http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf and you'll see the missing newline in the example. The following MWE will put them on the same line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig/bed1}
        \subcaption{Bedroom 1}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig/bed2}
        \subcaption{Bedroom 2}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Two bedrooms}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have removed the newline but result is still the same.

Comment: @CravingSpirit Did you compile this code? When I do (with the `demo` option to `graphicx` as I don't have the pictures) both subfigures are placed next to each other as advertised!

Comment: i see the problem now, I changed the width to 0.5, try it yourself and you will see it really doesn't work in that width, while if you remove the `\centering` line, everything will look as expected. Mysterious thing.

Comment: @CravingSpirit not really mysterious: with `0.5\linewidth` both minipages don't fit in a line anymore: there's also a space between them. With `\centering` they're placed below each other then. Without you'll get the warning `Overfull \hbox (2.22221pt too wide)`. If you add a `%` after the first `\end{minipage}` they'll fit again.

Comment: Ok. What is the `%` for? Thanks.

Comment: @CravingSpirit The `Overfull \hbox` message you get is due to the fact that an end-of-line is equivalent to a space; the `%` in dartbith's answer masks it so TeX doesn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

darthbith's answer is partially right, here is how I solved it:

1. remove the `\centering` line in the `figure` environment
2. remove the superfluous newline as darthbith suggested.

Comment: The centering line should have no effect on whether or not there is a new line in the figure...

Comment: Indeed it has. But maybe it also has something to do with the command you use to compile the doc? I use xelatex.

Comment: I use xelatex as well, but as with cgnieder, the `\centering` has no effect in terms of line breaks when I compile. Perhaps it has something to do with your fonts? I eliminated those in my MWE because they are not installed on my system.

Comment: The `\centering` has nothing to do with the problem posted in the question, see [my other comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126944/why-dont-these-figures-align-horizontally/126950#comment285565_126950)